# racadm failing to create virtual disks

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sshpass

We have a dell server with idrac 7 and I am trying to write a simple bash script to create a single virtual disks for all physical disks using racadm but it is failing. The flow is:

```
disks=`sshpass -p "$idracpasswd" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@someidracIP racadm raid get pdisks`
all_disks=$(echo $disks | sed 's/ /\,/g')
echo $all_disks

createvd=`sshpass -p "$idracpasswd" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@someidracIP racadm raid createvd:RAID.Integrated.1-1 -rl r0 -pdkey:$all_disks`
echo $createvd
```

Output of $all_disks is **Disk.Bay.0:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1,Disk.Bay.1:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1,Disk.Bay.2:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1,Disk.Bay.3:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1,Disk.Bay.4:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1,Disk.Bay.5:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1**

basically a string with comma separated physical disks. So the entire command is such

```
'sshpass -p *passwd* ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$line racadm raid createvd:RAID.Integrated.1-1 -rl r0 -pdkey:Disk.Bay.0:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1,Disk.Bay.1:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1,Disk.Bay.2:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1,Disk.Bay.3:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1,Disk.Bay.4:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1,Disk.Bay.5:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1`
```

But every time the script is failing with following error message

```
cmdstat
status       : 2
status_tag   : COMMAND PROCESSING FAILED
error        : 253
error_tag    : COMMAND NOT RECOGNIZED
```

The same command I fired from the racadm console and it works fine but from local its failing.

I am reading *$idracpasswd* and its value properly reflecting. So that is for sure not causing the issue. Did a search but didn't find any relevant links. Please guide me here.

Answer (score 0):

First selected F2 and then select device setting look at virtual disk configuration. You can see the raid disks on there if you want to delete all ofthem. Selected configuration virtual disk management clear configuration and then re create again selected all of the disk. You can sepearate raid 0-1-2-3-4-5-6